# breakpoints not working

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Blackberry application the debugger is not hitting on some breakpoints. I am working in Eclipse. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 17):

Quick checklist:

- are you debugging the app instead of running it?
- are the breakpoints shown in the Breakpoints view? (Debug perspective)
- is the "skip all breakpoints" enabled or disabled? (Breakpoints view)
- is the particular breakpoint enabled or disabled? (rightclick on breakpoint)
- are the breakpoints conditionally and is the condition met? (rightclick on breakpoint)
- is you debugger connected to the VM running the app? (Debug view, connect to process)
- are the breakpoints in the app you are actually running?
- and finally: are the breakpoints in code that gets executed by the VM?

Sanity checks:

- put a breakpoint at the application entry point (e.g. `main` method)
- mock up an Hello World app to test debugger behaviour
- 15 mins breaks now and then and breathing regularly is good for you

Comment: is the "skip all breakpoints" enabled or disabled? (Breakpoints view) ~ thanks. Never noticed that button

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the most up-to-date version of Java. There was a bug in a version a little while back that would cause breakpoints to be ignored. I had the same problems using J2SE in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Is the source code you are debugging the same compiled code you are running? They must be identical for your line breakpoints to trigger. If your running in eclipse try the following to confirm that your source is being compiled:

1. add a println statement just before your breakpoint - check this is printed
2. Try "clean all" ænd rebuild your project. Very occasionally I've had issues with eclipse not "building on save" and a restart or clean all has fixed it.